# Ordered messages in Masstransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have some requirements in my case to process messages in order, but not quite. I know ordering messages is bad, so I'll explain.

There is one producer that posts one message with timed intervals. This message contains a list of jobs to be executed. The message starts a saga, which sorts these jobs by their "weight" and prepares a batch of other messages for consumers (which are also sagas, if that matters). There are multiple consumers.

What I need now is to process these jobs in order which was prepared by initial saga. But i don't want other consumers to stall.

An example of what I'm talking about.

Imaging a batch of jobs: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"

If there is a limit of 4 consumers per queue, I want jobs "1, 2, 3, 4" to be consumed immediately. When any of jobs finishes, I want the next one to be consumed (in this case #5). And then #6 and so on.

If another batch is prepared by the time there is only "6, 7, 8" left in queue I want it to be sorted the same way. So if jobs "1, 2, 9, 10" arrive then resulting queue should become "**1, 2**, 6, 7, 8, **9, 10**", i.e. always sorted by "weight" and consumed in this order, so the next job has to be again "1", then "2" and so on.

Is this scheme possible somehow using Masstransit?
I know there is a chance that job "10" will never get processed, but that's not a problem in my case.

P.S. Using RabbitMQ.

Comment: The complexity of execution logic certainly seems like this is something you'd have to build yourself. On top of MassTransit, using sagas, sure, but you'll need to develop the scheduling/ordering logic yourself.

Comment: So i guess there is no way to "tune" MassTransit for this? Only "patch"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tune vs. patch, but like I said, this isn't something that MassTransit does out of the box.

Comment: What i meant by "tune" was something like a "replace one service with the other", but i get your point.

Comment: I had a similar(ish) issue, where what I needed to queue was actually not the same kind of data that MT is handling (messages for commands, events, etc). I used a MT saga to manage a queue for domain data, and let MT get on with the delivery of events, commands, responses (for enqueue, dequeue, etc). My domain queue works differently to a message queue, I am free to implement it exactly as I need using a state machine. I use a db to store the different queues and I also have management tools to help look after them. This isn't 'tuning' MT, it's just using it for what it is very good at :)

Comment: Yeah, i already figured that i need something "external" to MT to manage my queue. Something in the middle of producers and consumers to pre-process the messages after they are sent, but before consumed. Something like a proxy. Would be nice to have it out-of-the-box, but currently will have to implement my own.